# How to filter Logs from the Spark log4j-defaults.properties file in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, log4j

I am running a `Spark` job in IntelliJ using the `Maven` dependencies. The problem is that the console logs are triggered by the `log4j-defaults.properties` file from Spark and the logs are full of INFO logs that I really don't want to have.

I would like to modify the log file to get rid of the INFO logs (or any log). Or maybe filter the INFO logs without modifying the properties file. The problem is that I can not modify the `log4j-defaults.properties` file from the `Maven` dependency in IntelliJ, or at least I didn't find the way to do it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the spark context you can try:
`sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")`
and you will not see logs at all.
you can also use "ERROR" and it will only show logs that are error or above.

Valid log levels include: ALL, DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, OFF, TRACE, WARN

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Place these lines in the beginning of your spark-scala code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I am working with Java. I am trying and I am not sure how to make this operation in Java.

Comment: You can use the same code with java syntax, use log4j library.

Comment: Ok, I already implemented it in Java, in the main method, but I got all the same logs, starting with the sentence: `Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties`